# How get xml string from svg file?

Tags: jquery, html, xml, svg

```
var jqxhr = $.get('/download.svg', function () {

                })
         .done(function (data) {
              alert("done");
           })
```

I have a svg file saved in my local system and i got this file through jquery get 
which is working fine and returning a data document. I need to get xml string of that svg file. How can i get that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide relevant portions of your code, so we can help properly.

Comment: i just did this

var jqxhr = $.get('/download.svg', function () {
            
        })
                            .done(function (data) {
                                            alert("done");
                                 })

Now i want to get xml from this data

Comment: Try $.get('/download.svg', function () { }) .done(function (data) { console.log(data); })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `dataType` argument to `xml` when calling [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
$.get('/download.svg', function(svg) {
   console.log( svg );
}, 'xml');
```

With older jQuery versions, you might need to use `text` as data type:

```
$.get('/download.svg', function(svg) {
   console.log( svg );
}, 'text');
```

Comment: it did'nt return me xml

Comment: How to you test whether the return value is XML or not? Eventually, *SVG is XML*. Maybe its just your browser rendering the image directly, so you don't see any XML code.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to accept and upvote my answer.